# Sci-fi book series set in postapocalyptic frozen world with train colors representing class rank

Tags: story-identification, post-apocalyptic

I read it in Czech translation in the 90s. It was a series of books in a postapocalyptic frozen world with train traffic only - with different class (color ranking) and some kind of new human life form, which is better adapted to cold environment.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It sounds a bit like the movie *[Snowpiercer](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706620/)*, which is an adaptation of the french graphic novel *[Le Transperceneige](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Transperceneige)*, which is itself inspired by the french novels ***[La Compagnie des glaces / The Ice Company](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Compagnie_des_glaces)*** (sorry, link to the french wikipedia article, the english article is about its TV series adaptation, but it seems there is a [Czech article (**Ledová společnost**)](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ledov%C3%A1_spole%C4%8Dnost) about it). This may be what you are looking for.

Partial translation of the french wikipedia article:

> ***The Ice Company*** is a serie of science-fiction novels by G.-J. Arnaud published between 1980 and 1992 and then between 2001 and 2005. [...]
>
> *Summary*
>   A post-apocalyptic sight of Earth where the dust caused by an explosion of the moon covered Earth's atmosphere, blocking the sun rays and sending the planet into a new ice age. The survivors are forced to live in underdome cities interconnected only by trains. The big railways companies rule the networks and apply a totalitarian order on the population by hiding them the truth. The Red (or Red Men) are "able to resist temperatures below -40" and can live outside the cities.

As a side note about the color and painting, the french article about the graphic novel also mentions golden cars for the aristocracy.

Comment: And here is the ISFDB page for the [*Ice Company*](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?31133) series.

Comment: That's sounds like it, thank you very much! I will look into it.