# Movie where they spray a chemical into the atmosphere to cool the Earth down, causing a new ice age

Tags: story-identification, movie

What is the name of movie where they spray some kind of chemical into the atmosphere to cool down the Earth but then they end up using way too much and the Earth goes into another ice age.

Comment: Wasn't that the premise of [*Snowpiercer*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snowpiercer)?

Comment: Yes that’s it thank you

Comment: @SVC1313 you can accept a correct answer by clicking the checkmark on the left

Comment: I do not think a movie-ID question should be closed as a dupe of a book-ID question; however, it's certainly worth keeping a link to it: [Sci-fi book series set in postapocalyptic frozen world with train colors representing class rank](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/100825/98028). I've voted to reopen. EDIT: though, as I only remembered afterwards, my reopen vote is just as binding as Fuzzy's vote to close... leaving it for the community to decide if it has to re-go into a close vote process.

Answer (score 10):

*Snowpiercer* (2014)?

From [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1706620/plotsummary):

> **The nations release the substance CW-7 with the intention of controlling global warning, but accidentally it results in another Ice Age destroying Earth.** The only survivors live in the train Snowpiercer which is driven by a perpetual motion engine created by the millionaire Wilford (Ed Harris) that lives in the engine part. In 2031, after seventeen years, there is a fight of classes inside the train since the oppressed lower class lives in dreadful conditions in the last wagons of the train while the elite lives in the front wagons. The lower class is fed with protein bars only; they are oppressed and punished by Minister Mason (Tilda Swinton) and her brutal guards; and their children are taken every now and then when they reach a certain height. [...]

Comment: For those that haven't seen the movie and think the above description sounds a bit ridiculous, rest assured, it is actually far far worse than it sounds.